# Html5 content edit also change with source code

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create my small html editor with using html5

`<section contenteditable="true">
 Edit here
</section>`

so, when i use it's make specified region editable but how i change also its source code 
with their front code, is this possible with any simple way or javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this article](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/03/12/wysiwyg-html-editor/). The archive behind the link "grab the archive" contains the code for a simple HTML 5 editor. Ignore Qt, you can open the HTML in a web browser and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php script that change your html and with ajax send edited content to that script.